# Move subview of a cell to the front swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cell, layer

I have a cell with a button on it. When I press the button, I start an animation indicating something is preparing. I do this within the `@IBAction` function like so: (this is in my custom tableViewCell function).

```
@IBAction func playNowTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let loadingShape = CAShapeLayer()
    //Some animating of the shape
}
```

I define this shape within the `@IBAction` as the process should repeat if I press the button again

However, because only the necessary cells displayed on the device are loaded in one chunk in the `cellForRowAt` function for the tableView, my animation repeats every few cells if I scroll down while the animation is loading.

What I have done so far is append to a list of all the previously pressed buttons in my by defining a function and calling it in the `@IBAction` function of the button like so:

```
func findCell() {
    //Iterate tableView list and compare to current cellText
    for value in list {
        if value == cellText.text {
             //If found, checking if value is already stored in pressedBefore
             for selected in pressedBefore {
                 if selected == value { return }
             }
             alreadyPlay.append(song: cellText.text!)
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in my `cellForRowAt` function, I simply make a reverse operation, which checks if the current index in the list is the same as any value in the already selected ones.

Having all of these filtered out, I now only have a list of the non-selected ones.However, I do not know what to do now.

Weirdly, `cell.bringSubview(tofront: cell.cellText) 
cell.bringSubview(tofront: cell.buttonText)` does NOT change the order of the subviews. What would do I do now? Is it possible that `CAShapeLayer()` is not regarded as a subview, but only a layer?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Weirdly, cell.bringSubview(tofront: cell.cellText) 
cell.bringSubview(tofront: cell.buttonText) does NOT change the order of the subviews. What would do I do now?*

bringSubview(tofront:) only works with direct subviews. Traditionally your cellText and buttonText are subviews to [cell.contentView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623229-contentview).

so try

```
cell.contentView.bringSubview(tofront: cell.buttonText)
```

---

*Is it possible that CAShapeLayer() is not regarded as a subview, but
    only a layer?*

Yes, CAShapeLayer inherits from CALayer and only regarded as a layer to its view and will likely need to be updated via [layoutSubviews()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622482-layoutsubviews) or [draw()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622529-draw)

---

Saw those nested for loops and if statements, thought I'd offer a way to clean that up a bit.

```
func findCell() {
    //find list elements that match cell's text and ensure it hasn't been pressed before
    list.filter { $0 == cellText.text && !pressedBefore.contains($0) }.forEach {
        alreadyPlay.append(alreadyPlayed(song: LeLabelOne.text!, artist: leLabelThree.text!))
    }
}

// alternative using Sets
func findCell() {
    let cellTextSet = Set(list).intersection([cellText.text])

    // find entries in cellTextSet that haven't been pressed before
    cellTextSet.subtract(Set(pressedBefore)).forEach {
        alreadyPlay.append(alreadyPlayed(song: LeLabelOne.text!, artist: leLabelThree.text!))
    }
}
```

---